My client's second sent packet is not received by server
I am writing an ssh client in C. Currently, my client is able to send the server it's ssh protocol version, and receive the server's version in return. My issue arises when I try and send the key exchange init packet to the server. I know that the kex packet is not well formed, but I wanted to see (via Wireshark) if the server was receiving anything, and it was not. The client is able to receive the server's kex init message. If I swap the order the client sends the packets (kex first, protocol second), the server receives a malformed kex packet.
The code is definitely rough around the edges/unfinished. The kex packet is definitely incorrect, I've been prioritizing getting the packet to be received by the server before I fix the contents of the packet.  I've left a lot of print statements in to try and help my debugging.
Initiate TCP connection:
int start_client(const char *host, const int port) {
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sock = 0;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(22); 

    inet_pton(AF_INET, host, &address.sin_addr);

    int output = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    
    if (output == 0) {
        printf("successful connection\n");
    } else {
        printf("no connection\n");
    }

    sendProtocol(sock);

    sendKexInit(sock);

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}

Send protocol packet:
int sendProtocol(int sock) {
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);  // Clear the buffer

    char *protocol = "SSH-2.0-mySSH\r\n";
    int sentBytes = send(sock, protocol, strlen(protocol), 0);

    if (sentBytes != -1) {
        printf("Successful protocol send! Number of protocol bytes sent: %i\n", sentBytes);
    } else {
        printf("Send did not complete successfully.\n");
    }
    
    ssize_t bytesRecieved = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    
    if (bytesRecieved > 0) {
        printf("server protocol: %s", buffer);
    } else {
        printf("No server protocol recieved :(\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

Send (malformed) kex packet:
int sendKexInit (int sock) {
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);  // Clear the buffer

    unsigned char *cookie = generateRandomBytes(16);

    // // this is hardcoded, just trying to get it to work
    uint32_t packetLen = 24;
    packetLen = htonl(packetLen); // fix endian-ness
    memcpy(buffer, &packetLen, sizeof(packetLen)); 
    buffer[4] = 6;

    buffer[5] = SSH_MSG_KEXINIT;
    memcpy(buffer + 6, cookie, 16); 
    free(cookie);
    memset(buffer + 22, 0, 2);
    
    int sentBytes = send(sock, buffer, 24, 0);
    if (sentBytes != -1) {
        printf("Successful kex send! Number of kex bytes sent: %i\n", sentBytes);
    } else {
        printf("Send did not complete successfully.\n");
    }
    
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);  // Clear the buffer
    ssize_t bytes_recieved = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    
    if (bytes_recieved > 0) {
        printf("response: %s\n", buffer);
    } else {
        printf("No server response recieved :(\n");
    }

    // printing out some of the response (buffer is too small for all of it)
    // for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
    //     printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
    // }
    // printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

Is there something obvious that I'm missing that's causing my second send() to not go through?
I have tried moving the ordering of the send() calls around. The result of this is that the first call is received by the server and the second is not. My current best guess is that I'm not closing out the first send correctly, but the send() function returns a value that appears correct (the number of bytes in the buffer that I am sending).

Just to confirm, which is it that fails, send() or recv()? It sounds like send(), but it's not clear. What is the value of errno on error? And what is the value of BUFFER_SIZE, just in case.

Just to clarify, you use a standard server, and observe that the sent data isn't visible at all on the server host? Also, your program is blocking on the last recv right? If you don't end your exchange with a blocking recv, you may need to set SO_LINGER to ensure data is sent before closing the socket.

@KenY-N BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 - this is just some arbitrary size I chose. Neither send() nor recv() fail. Both return the expected return value of a successful call. The issue is that the server does not actually receive the packet that send() appears to have sent (from its return value).

@ElderBug I am using a standard SSH server running on a VM (Kali). My client is running on my machine. I'm using Wireshark to monitor the packets sent between my machine and the VM.
My client receives the server's second message just fine (I left a commented out block of code in the kex block that I used to verify this by comparing the print out to the Wireshark packet), the issue is that the server doesn't seem to be receiving the second message my client sends.

You are using a stream protocol.  It is therefore unsafe to assume that each exchange consists of a single packet.  It is likewise unsafe to assume that each send() or recv() will transfer the full number of bytes requested.  And it is unsafe to assume that send() calls on one side will pair 1:1 with recv() calls on the other.  I'm not sure that any of that is related to the issue you're presently working on, but it is all essential knowledge for anyone doing network programming, and your prose and code do not reflect awareness of it.

From "I wanted to see (via Wireshark) if the server was receiving anything", I conclude that you are running Wireshark on the server.  It would be worthwhile to also get the client-side view, to be sure that the problem is not in the network between the two (manifesting as the client putting data on the wire but it not reaching the server).

"The issue is that the server does not actually receive the packet that send() appears to have sent (from its return value)" -- this is a misunderstanding of the return value of send().  A successful return from send indicates that the indicated number of bytes have been queued for transmission.  It does not imply that they have actually been put on the wire, and often they will not have been.  But the system does not foresee any issue with following through on that, and you can normally expect that it will do so soon.

@JohnBollinger I was missing the stream element. I added the null terminator to the end of my first packet and that fixed my issue. Thank you!
